# How to store descriptor using Vladmandic face-api.js

Tags: server, node-modules, detection, descriptor, face

I want to store faces descriptor in single local file using vladmandic face-api.js on node server side when images are added in images folder automatically images descriptor should get stored in single descriptor Json file and when comparison required it should fetch stored descriptor

I tried but the descriptor is unable to store in local Json file